# Когда использую автозаполнения от google в input тегах типа text, появляется какой-то странный background

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Наверное, есть какой-то псевдо-класс, в котором это можно изменить, но я ничего не нашёл. Подскажите, как это убрать?

[image: input type="text"]
[image: input type="text"]

Answer (score 2):

Можно полность отключить подсказки, добавив `autocomplete="off"`:

> `<input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off">`

Можно фон автозаполняемого содержимого заменить на какой-либо цвет средством `box-shadow`:

> `/* Подставить свой цвет вместо white */
>   input:-webkit-autofill,
>   input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
>   input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
>   input:-webkit-autofill:active  {
>       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset !important;
>   }`

А оставить прозрачным, насколько я знаю, не получиться